# Delete all users in mobile push

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

We've changed the way we identify users in our app and, as such, I need to remove all users currently in our Mobile Push contacts list in Salesforce Marketing Cloud (so that it can repopulate with the correct user ids.

I've had a look around and can't see an option to remove people on this list. Has anyone found a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hew,

There's no way to remove contacts from the UI.

Instead, I recommend you create a new attribute 'oldUser' or some such, and mark all existing users as 'oldUsers'. Once you've done this, you can create new filtered lists, etc. that include 'not oldUser = true'